# ExpressJS - Serving Multiple Web Apps with Different Base Directories on the Same Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to serve a website with different static directories for different routes.

- If a get request is made to the `/tools*` route, I would like to use the `/dist/toolsApp/` directory as the base directory for my frontend code.
- If a get request is made to the `/net*` route, I would like to use the `/dist/netIdApp/` directory as the base directory for my frontend code.
- If a get request is made to the * route, I would like to use the `/dist/homeApp/` directory as the base directory for my frontend code.

I'm having difficulty determining where to insert the  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + DIRECTORY));` lines of code. I initially was trying the below code, but quickly realized that this code wasn't right because I do not want to merge the directories (they have conflicting file names).

```
// Tools Routes
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/'));
app.get('/tools*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/index.html'));
    });

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/'));
// Net-Id Authenticated Routes
app.get('/net*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/index.html'));
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp'));
// Default Route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp/index.html'));
});
```

I then tried specify a route for each of the app.uses, as shown below. And that only seemed to ever send the last route (I also tried changing the last app.use from '*' to '/' and that didn't change anything). The result of this is that the frontend get requests end up having a '/' appended after the file name, making it so that the Express server interprets the request to be for a directory, not a regular file. I'm really unsure as to why this is happening.

```
// Tools Routes
app.use('/tools*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/'));
app.get('/tools*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/index.html'));
    });

app.use('/net*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/'));
// Net-Id Authenticated Routes
app.get('/net*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/index.html'));
});


app.use('*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp'));
// Default Route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp/index.html'));
});
```

Lastly, I've tried putting the line within the respective app.get, but that wasn't working correctly (express doesn't send the frontend files).

```
// Tools Routes
app.get('/tools*', function(req, res) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/'));
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/index.html'));
    });

// Net-Id Authenticated Routes
app.get('/net*', function(req, res) {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/index.html'));
});

// Default Route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp/index.html'));
});
```

Could someone help me determine what the best way to do this is?
Node: v8.11.2
Express:

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve the issue, the following code did work, it just puts the files in the address.com/tools/, address.com/net/, and address.com/, respectively.

```
// Tools Routes
app.use('/tools*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/'));
app.get('/tools*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/toolsApp/index.html'));
    });

app.use('/net*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/'));
// Net-Id Authenticated Routes
app.get('/net*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/netIdApp/index.html'));
});


app.use('*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp'));
// Default Route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/homeApp/index.html'));
});
```